# How do I tell Nginx to skip rewrite some specific location?

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

This is what I do:

Because `/api` system has problem with HTTPS, I have to serve it under HTTP. The rest I force them to be in HTTPS. 
However, in my django system, redirects gives me back http. It may have to do with django, but for now, I want to rewrite all HTTP to HTTPs. I normally would put that inside the `80` server block, but I want to keep `/api` as HTTP.

How can I do that using rewrite?

Thanks.

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
        server_name_in_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 100M;

        location /api {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
            proxy_redirect default;
        }

    }
    server {

        listen 443;
        ssl on;

        location /app1 {
         ....
         proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
        }

        location /app2 {
         ... 
         proxy_pass http://localhost:5678;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I just tried something and it looks like it's working.

```
if ($request_uri !~ (/api)){
    rewrite     ^(.*)   https://$http_host$1 permanent;
}
```

and then leave everything else in the `80` block intact...
Not gonna check my answer off...